# Querying using related field names

Tags: django

I've got two models that I'd like to perform a reverse search on. I'm wondering how to do this given the fact that one model has to fields with foreign keys to the same model.

```
class Review(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)

class Cart(models.Model):
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True) 

class Job(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, related_name="cart_one",  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True) 
    unscheduled_job = models.ForeignKey(Cart, related_name="cart_two", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

My query is as follows:

```
reviews = Review.objects.filter(cart__job__employee=employee)
```

This query is failing due to the fact that the Job model has two foreign keys that point to the cart model. How would I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Show the Cart model?

Comment: added this to my question. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify a [**`related_query_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) or a [**`related_name=…` parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), then that is the name to access the model in reverse, so you can query with:

```
Review.objects.filter(cart__cart_one__employee=employee)
```

or if you want to query in reverse with the `unscheduled_job`, then it is:

```
Review.objects.filter(cart__cart_two__employee=employee)
```

You can also combine the two, so bo5th `cart` anfd `unscheduled_job` by making use of a `Q` object:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Review.objects.filter(Q(cart__cart_one__employee=employee) | Q(cart__cart_two__employee))
```

You might however want to change the `related_name=…`s, since this should be the name to access the `Job` object from the perspective of a `Cart` model.